# how to use multiple times the stage event in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code:

```
stop();
import gs.*; 
import gs.easing.*;
import gs.TweenMax;


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // Add the button click

function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {
TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});

}

var grav:Number = 7.5;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var jumpPow:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // Add the button click

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function spring(e:MouseEvent):void {

        if(jumping != true)
        {   
            TweenLite.to(man, 0.5, {rotation:360});
            jumpPow = -50;
            jumping = true;
        }
    }   



function update(evt:Event):void
{
    if(jumping)
    {
        man.y += jumpPow;
        jumpPow += grav;

        if(man.y >= 375)
        {
            jumping = false;
            man.y = 375;
                    }
    }
}
```

but now if I click on the stage both the objects start to tween or something. but it needs to be like this: if I click the stage: first function rijden needs to be activated, on a second Click on the stage function spring needs to be activated.
Can someone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reformat your code like this:

```
//...

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // Add the button click

function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {

     stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // unplug "rijden" handler
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // Add the button click

     TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});

}

var grav:Number = 7.5;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var jumpPow:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function spring(e:MouseEvent):void {

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // unplug "spring" handler

    if(jumping != true)
        {   
            TweenLite.to(man, 0.5, {rotation:360});
            jumpPow = -50;
            jumping = true;
        }  

}  

//...
```

Comment: @Chernic it has to be like this: If I click the stage once function rijden starts, if I click the stage twice function spring starts

Comment: @Chernic this was exactly what I wanted, but how can I reset it again, because if I click now twice nothing happens

Comment: @user2852398 you can add this line : `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden);` in your `spring` function again